# Implementing a countdown timer to an HTML page that collects items from a JSON file

Tags: javascript, html, json, timer, countdown

I would like to add a countdown timer to an HTML page that collects data from a JSON file using JavaScript.

The code in JavaScript to visualize products:

```js
function displayProducts (products) {
  let result = '';
  products.forEach(product => {
    result += `
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-4">
              <img src=${product.image} alt="product" class="product-img">
              <h4>${product.title}</h4>
              <p>$${product.price}</p>
              <button class="add-to-cart" data-id=${product.id}>Add to cart</button>
          </div>
      </div>
      `;
  });
  productsDOM.innerHTML = result;
}
```

The items/product information are located in a JSON file.
I want the countdown timer to be shown in between the title and the price of each product.
I already have a working timer:

```js
const startingMinutes = 5;
let time = startingMinutes * 60;

const countdownEl = document.getElementById('countdown');

setInterval(updateCountdown, 1000);

function updateCountdown () {
  const minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
  let seconds = time % 60;

  seconds = seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds;

  countdownEl.innerHTML = `${minutes}:${seconds}`;
  time--;
}
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to show a timer on each product listing, you won't be able to use `getElementById()` to access the DOM (`getElementbyId` can only access a single DOM element).

You need to create several DOM elements and assign them a unique class, like this:

```html
<h4>${product.title}</h4>

<!-- add this: -->
<p class="timerdisplay"></p>

<p>$${product.price}</p>
```

Then update the DOM elements like this:

```js
// obtain all the 'timerdisplay` elements
const pTimers = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.timerdisplay'));

...

// loop through each timer element
pTimers.forEach(p => {
  // set the time string here
});
```